# "where" in mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am using a code that is using mysql. I am very new in mysql so I would be thankful if you could help. My input is a huge dumpfile of wikipediapages in xml bz2 format. The input format is some text files extracted from that xml file with this format:

```
<doc id="12" url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=12" title="Anarchism"> text... </doc>
```

the only parts that connects the program to sql is as follows:

```
def read_in_STOP_CATS(f_n = "/media/sscepano/Data/Wiki2015/STOPCAT/STOP_CATS.txt"):
    s = []
    f = open(f_n, "r")
    for line in f:
            s.append(line.rstrip().lower())
    return s

def connect_2_db():
    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='test', password='test',
                                  host='127.0.0.1',
                                  database='wiki_category_links')
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print("Database does not exist")
        else:
            print(err)
    return cnx


def articles_selected(aid):
    global cnx
    global STOP_CATS
    cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM categorylinks where cl_from = " + str(aid))

    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row is not None:
        #print(row)
        cat = row[1].lower()
        #print cat
        for el in STOP_CATS:
            if el in cat:
                return False
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    return True

cnx = connect_2_db()
STOP_CATS = read_in_STOP_CATS()
TITLE_WEIGHT = 4
```

my problem is that right now I do not know how should I connect to mysql to be able to run the code and the main prob;lem is that I do not know what is categorylinks in the code? That should be the name of my sql table? Does it mean that I need to make an sql table with this name and import all my text file in this one table?
what does 'where' means in this line also????

Comment: Not a python guy, but I would say you need to wrap the value `str(aid)` in quoutes to conform to SQL Syntax so you need to make it look like this `WHERE cl_from = 'some string'`. Sorry dont know how to do that in Python

Answer (score 1):

As RiggsFolly said, you need to get something like `WHERE cl_from = 'some string'`
You could do it this way:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM categorylinks where cl_from ='" + str(aid)+"'")
```

But it is better to use prepared statements like this one:

```
select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM categorylinks where cl_from = %(aid)s"
cursor.execute(select_stmt, { 'aid':str(aid) })
```

So in your code you have:

> A database named **wiki_category_links**
>
> In that database you have a table called **categorylinks**

And the select you have means that you are going to get, from table categorylinks, all rows that have the column cl_from equal to the value of aid variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Actually I downloaded the code from github : https://github.com/sanja7s/SR_Wiki_ESA. But right now is it  needed to make any table by myself or change the host, user and pass? I do not see any db file in the whole package of github. So I have concern whether I have to make a table by myself?